# highlight a form with clojure's comment macro in vim

Tags: vim, syntax, clojure, lisp, vim-syntax-highlighting

In clojure, you can use `#_` to comment out the next form. For example

```
#_(foo 2 3 4)
#_foo
#_{:a '(1 2 3) :b [1 2 3]}
```

will comment out the above list, symbol and map. Like Emacs, I would expect **and want that the form would get the syntax highlightning of a comment**.

In vim, there is no default syntax highlighting for commented-out-forms. I have also not found any plugin that does this. Have anyone tried to configure this? Thankful for any help.

Comment: And why won't comment with semi-colon? That works for me with Vim and it's even supported by plugins

Comment: Because you cant comment out forms with a semicolon without breaking paranthenis symmetry

Answer (score 1):

The `vim-clojure-static` plugin has not enabled commenting out using the `#_` form because it disabled REPL integration for the commented out block (see https://github.com/guns/vim-clojure-static/issues/60).

In the issue that addresses this (linked above) @guns provided the following addition to the syntax file to enable highlighting of comments:

`" WARNING: This code has the following KNOWN deficiencies:
"
"   · Consecutive #_ macros are not matched correctly:
"       (list #_#_ 1 2 3) ;; => (3)
"   · Bracket character literals within #_ comment regions break syntax:
"       #_[\a \[ \] \b] ;; broken
"   · Compound forms preceded by reader metacharacters are unmatched:
"       #_'(α β γ) ;; broken
"   · Atomic forms preceded by reader metacharacters + whitespace are unmatched:
"       #_' foo ;; broken
"
syntax match  clojureCommentAtom            /\v#_[ \t\r\n]*[^()\[\]{} \t\r\n]+/
syntax region clojureCommentListContained   start=/(/  end=/)/ contains=clojureCommentListContained,clojureCommentVectorContained,clojureCommentMapContained,clojureCommentStringContained contained
syntax region clojureCommentVectorContained start=/\[/ end=/]/ contains=clojureCommentListContained,clojureCommentVectorContained,clojureCommentMapContained,clojureCommentStringContained contained
syntax region clojureCommentMapContained    start=/{/  end=/}/ contains=clojureCommentListContained,clojureCommentVectorContained,clojureCommentMapContained,clojureCommentStringContained contained
syntax region clojureCommentStringContained start=/"/  skip=/\v\\\\|\\"/ end=/"/ contained
syntax region clojureCommentList            matchgroup=clojureCommentDelimiter start=/\v#_[ \t\r\n]*\(/ end=/)/ contains=clojureCommentListContained,clojureCommentVectorContained,clojureCommentMapContained,clojureCommentStringContained
syntax region clojureCommentVector          matchgroup=clojureCommentDelimiter start=/\v#_[ \t\r\n]*\[/ end=/]/ contains=clojureCommentListContained,clojureCommentVectorContained,clojureCommentMapContained,clojureCommentStringContained
syntax region clojureCommentMap             matchgroup=clojureCommentDelimiter start=/\v#_[ \t\r\n]*\{/ end=/}/ contains=clojureCommentListContained,clojureCommentVectorContained,clojureCommentMapContained,clojureCommentStringContained
syntax region clojureCommentString          matchgroup=clojureCommentDelimiter start=/\v#_[ \t\r\n]*"/  skip=/\v\\\\|\\"/ end=/"/
highlight link clojureCommentDelimiter       clojureComment
highlight link clojureCommentAtom            clojureComment
highlight link clojureCommentListContained   clojureComment
highlight link clojureCommentVectorContained clojureComment
highlight link clojureCommentMapContained    clojureComment
highlight link clojureCommentStringContained clojureComment
highlight link clojureCommentList            clojureComment
highlight link clojureCommentVector          clojureComment
highlight link clojureCommentMap             clojureComment
highlight link clojureCommentString          clojureComment`

I personally use [Spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs) (Emacs with Vim bindings and batteries included) with [Clojure layer](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Blang/clojure), and there comments and REPL integration both work fine, but I believe you are aware of this.